# How can I improve the ease of which I can extend my software?

Tags: extensibility, quality-attributes

I am thinking about how software like Microsoft Windows grows from small as MS-DOS to Windows 7, Adobe Photoshop from its first version to version CS5. What techniques were used to accomplish this? Did they extend their software from the existing software or redesign for the next version? Or have they already planned their software solidly before they built them?

It's hard for me to extend my application/software when I need to add new features and it makes a mess of other existing features. How can I improve my software's extensibility so that I can easily add new features to your software?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

By Implementing A strongly Designed system. with the best design patterns suited for the job.

> In software engineering, [extensibility](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extensibility)
>   (sometimes confused with forward
>   compatibility) **is a system design
>   principle** where the implementation
>   takes into consideration future
>   growth. It is a systemic measure of
>   the ability to extend a system and the
>   level of effort required to implement
>   the extension. Extensions can be
>   through the addition of new
>   functionality or through modification
>   of existing functionality. **The central
>   theme is to provide for change while
>   minimizing impact to existing system
>   functions.**

Few Important Aspects.

- [The Philosophy of Extensible Software](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_development_philosophies)
- [Designing extensible software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/323202/designing-extensible-software-plugin-architecture)
- [How extensible should code actually be?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896399/how-extensible-should-code-actually-be)

Answer (score 1):

Your code is more likely to be extensible if you follow the [SOLID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid_%28object-oriented_design%29) Priciple. Many of these come for free if you do [testdriven development](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Test-driven_development)

Answer (score 0):

Write modular code that is loosely coupled. This allows for extension in stages.